# push other branches in source tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a proyect in sourceTree with a branch feature/user_unit. When a get push, it appears only master. But I don´t watch my feature/user_unit to push. How I can resolve this problem?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-sourcetree

Comment: I am using azure Repository with git

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps but good for you

Comment: You do not have a local branch feature/user_unit so there is nothing but master to push.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a local branch feature/user_unit so there is nothing but master to push. You would need to checkout feature/user_unit, edit add and commit, and then you could push the new commit.